# Linux CLI Make a Tar.Gz with Tar.Gz First-level Directories

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, directory, tar, gzip

Currently, I use this command to make tar.gz archives:

```
sudo tar -zcpvf archive.tar.gz directory1 directory2 directory3
```

Is there a way to compress multiple archives like above, but instead of compressing regular folders, have tar make sub tar.gz files? So, for example, I want to be able to make archive.tar.gz and see it contain directory1.tar.gz, directory2.tar.gz and directory3.tar.gz on the first level folders only.

I know I can compress directory1, directory2, and directory3 individually and then add them to another archive, but is there a way to do what I'm asking with one command?

Answer (score 0):

No other way than compressing directory1, directory2 and directory3 beforehand, sorry.

Comment: Of course, you can build a command to do the whole zipping as a one-liner.